# This for loop returns the right binary value but appends a lot of 0 to it, why does it do that?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, binary, decimal

For an exercise I wrote this little loop to convert decimal number into a binary one. It returns the right value, I tested it, but it appends a hell lot of zeros to the output.

```
$dec = 17;

$bin = null;

while($dec != 0)
{
    $bin .= $dec % 2;
    $dec /= 2;
    round($dec, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
}

echo $bin;
```

I really can't tell why this is, am I blind? Can you give me an explanation? I would appreciate it.

I tried to test for `$dec == 0` and if that succeeds `break;` like so:

```
while($dec != 0)
{
    $bin .= $dec % 2;
    $dec /= 2;
    round($dec, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    if($dec == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

That didn't work. So I'm searching for a solution.
Thanks for the help in advance!
Jona

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What about checking in each loop which `$dec` value is used? What is the **expected** output of your code?

Comment: your issue is with `round($dec, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);`. remove this and use `$dec = floor($dec / 2)` instead too peform integer division

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your loop is that `$dec /= 2` is not an integer division. If you print out `$dec` in your loop you will see the values are 8.5, 4.25, 2.125, ... and so on until eventually `$dec` becomes the smallest possible double precision value, at which point in the next loop it finally becomes 0. Although you are calling `round`, which should fix that, you are not assigning the output of `round` to `$dec` so it has no effect. It's probably preferable to do an integer division to begin with. In PHP7 and up you can use [`intdiv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php):

```
$dec = intdiv($dec, 2);
```

Or in any PHP version a simple right shift works:

```
$dec = $dec >> 1;
```

Otherwise you can use [`intval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), [`floor`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) or [`round`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) or an `(int)` cast to convert the floating point result to an integer:

```
$dec = intval($dec / 2);
$dec = floor($dec / 2);
$dec = round($dec / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
$dec = (int)($dec / 2);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MsVZe)

The other problem is that you need to push the values into the `$bin` string in reverse order, so you need to replace

```
$bin .= $dec % 2;
```

with

```
$bin = ($dec % 2) . $bin;
```

So an example loop would be:

```
$dec = 24;    
$bin = null;
while($dec != 0)
{
    $bin = ($dec % 2) . $bin;
    $dec = $dec >> 1;
}
echo $bin . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
11000
```

Comment: Or with the given code the obvious `$dec = round($dec, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver was just adding that to the answer as you were typing the comment...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've found your problem: if you had debugged your loop, you would have seen that `$dec` is just halfed in each step. The call to `round` does not do anything, as you don't use the returned value. Just assign that to `$dec`